# create a video from image sequence in open cv

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I am working on open cv with c++.I have around 30 frames of images .I need to combine these frames to obtain a video.Can anyone suggest me method?Is it like reading each frames and storing in videowriter?Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using ffmpeg. You can do it programmatically or using the command line. An example of doing this on the command line is:

```
ffmpeg -start_number n -i image%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 test.avi
```

Where n is the first image number.

Comment: i want to do it  programmatically on open cv not on command line

Comment: I've never used OpenCV for that, only image processing. I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Tutorial how to do Videooutput](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.1/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html)

You will be asked for the codec you want to use. It's a bit complicated, but there are already many codec related questions on SO.

This code should work (not tested):

```
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  // Video write

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *window_name){
    vector<Mat> images; //fill this somehow
    Size S = vector[0].getSize();    

    VideoWriter outputVideo;  // Open the output
    outputVideo.open(NAME  , ex=-1, 30), S, true);  //30 for 30 fps

    if (!outputVideo.isOpened()){
        cout  << "Could not open the output video for write: "<< endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++){
        outputVideo << res;
    }

    cout << "Finished writing" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's up to you to fill your images into the vector. You can do it with command line arguments, or hardcode it, or do it some other way...